# PXE Boot Lenovo Ideapad Miix 510 with USB 3.0 Ultra Dock

Tags: boot, usb, deployment, pxe, sccm

I'm attempting to image a Lenovo Ideapad Miix 510 (Win10) using SCCM 2012 R2. Since the tablet has no natural ethernet connection, I have it hooked up to a Lenovo USB 3.0 Ultra Dock. I am able to see the ethernet connection via the boot menu, but when I begin the PXE boot, I am not able to proceed any farther than the "press f12 for network service boot". At which point, when I hit f12 it does nothing and then I get a response that says "no more network devices".

What I have done:

- Installed the drivers supporting the usb dock via SCCM boot image.
- Researched that the dock and tablet are capable of being booted via PXE (Everything I have found says they are).
- Attempted to import the ethernet driver that the tablet itself installs when hooked up to any usb ethernet adapter (I am unable to import this to SCCM - no supported platforms it says).
- Ensured that secure boot is off and legacy boot is enabled.
- Have attempted to research the PXE message "no more network devices" but came up empty handed.

Anyone have any ideas about this, I'm able to find tons of questions regarding this model of tablet, but no real answers to being able to PXE boot it successfully. I have also tried the regular Lenovo Ethernet Adapter 3.0, but no success there as I could not install that driver to the boot image in SCCM (same no supported platforms error).

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of duplicate MACID of ultra dock. Also please check whether the macid is already present in the SCCM DB or not. If so, try to remove the duplicate macid and try again